# Notice period while on furlough

Tags: resignation, notice-period, covid-19, furlough

as I have decided to move back home at the beginning of  June, I wondered if it was possible for me to handle the 4 weeks notice by 1st May and keep going till may 31st as furloughed?
I assume the terms of my contract, which states that in case I had, I should provide a month notice period, remains the same, correct?

Note, my company has already “furloughed me” for the whole April and planning to do the same for the month of May.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are from the UK? Please add a country tag, as local laws and regulations play a large part in this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe furlough changes anything about your notice period. If you are expected to give a month's notice under normal circumstances, then you should be able to give a month's notice while on furlough. Notice is about an amount of elapsed time, not an amount of work done.

A few things may happen. The company may allow you to end your employment early (they can't force that, though I'm not sure what difference it would make). They may conceivably "unfurlough" you, if they think there is essential work that you need to do before you go, such as documenting your job so the next person knows how to do it.